# Vistual Studio 2017 C# Diagnostic Tools what does it mean when a functions closing parenthesis is taking up lots of your time?

Tags: c#, diagnostics

I am running the diagnostic tools on my code to look for places to improve performance and a large portion of the CPU Time is assigned to functions closing braces.

What does this mean?

How do I improve the performance from this?

[image]

Comment: Percent is not everything.  What is the actual _elapsed time_ compared to everything else?   How often is it called?  Is it in a loop?  Is this in your game loop or asset load?

Comment: What other numbers do you have for this method? None of the other visible lines has any numbers, so this might just be somehow inaccurately placed or summing up over several lines.

Comment: @MickyD This is the draw call.